# Бот на python для telegram - проверка пользователя в сети

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Хочу написать бота для Telegram на языке Python.
я делаю бота который будет проверять мой канал на наличия ботов , как мне это сделать ? есть какие-то статьи для проверки пользователя на ботов без капч и тд ?
Заранее спасибо !

Comment: получите список участников и пройдитесь по каждому, в информации имеется флаг is_bot, если True - Бот, False нет. а так же первично можно понять бот или нет по никнейму (тот что @) у ботов всегда _bot_ как того требует ОтецБотов: _Now let's choose a username for your bot. It must end in `bot`_. Да, человек тоже так может, но будет ли?

Answer (score 1):

Советую поизучать довольно удобную и в относительно простую библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI (https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/), и посмотреть на ютубе всякие ролики про ботов в телеграмм, только потом уже начинать писать небольших ботов, и прочтя уже нужные части библиотеки для решения своей задачи. Это долгий путь, но верный, так вы будете понимать что пишете, и сможете писать ботов и покруче.

Comment: Спасибо , мне интересно можно проверть был ли пользователь онлайн , и если api не даёт доступа то как проверить пользователь бот или нет .

Comment: можно проверить если пользователь пришлёт сообщение боту, в данных сообщения которое можно вывести, можно узнать, является пользователь ботом или нет, а на счёт онлайна пока не знаю